# Creating a .template file for a program in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, templates

Hello to the users of Stack Overflow,

I am doing a C++ programming assignment and rather than writing in a .cpp file our professor wants us to write the file in .template. I am using Xcode and trying to open a .template file results in the 'Pages' app opening. Anyone know how to open and or create a .template file on Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your professor wants you to use some flavor of Linux or UNIX.  I've never heard of "`.template`" files before.  Xcode knows what to do with .cpp and .hpp files out of the box.

[According to posts in this thread](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=346982), you can add "`.template`" files are a new rule for source files, where they will be compiled.

As for opening `.template` files with Xcode automatically, if you do "Get Info" in the Finder on that file, you can set all files with that extension to be opened by Xcode instead of Pages.